# how to use spinners generated from android-holo-colors

Tags: android, android-spinner

Looking for ways to customize my spinner, I heard about http://android-holo-colors.com so I went there and generated a spinner. When I download the zip, it only contains a res file that has no layout folder. How would I use the generated spinner in a simple bare bone android app? As in I imagine I have to link the generated files to a spinner that I create in a layout file. How would I do that? Say my spinner in the layout is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How do I wire it up with the generated res stuff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tool generates a custom pair of theme and styles XML. You should use the theme for your activity/application, or even use only the styles you need.

EDIT: added an example as requested

Given you chose "MyApp" during generation, the zip will contain (besides the drawables and a theme definition) a set of styles (**res/values/myapp_styles.xml** and **res/values-v11/myapp_styles.xml**).

In order to use such resources within your layout you have to:

- merge the generated **res/** folder into your project **res/** folder
- use the given styles in your layouts accordingly.

eg:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
style="@style/SpinnerAppTheme"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

where **@style/SpinnerAppTheme** refers to the spinner-specific style defined in **res/values/myapp_styles.xml** (and **res/values-v11/myapp_styles.xml** for API>=11).

Comment: tagging @Jaws212 as well: +1 for trying to help. But I think your answer overestimate my knowledge of android a bit. Do you mind including an example of a simple linearlayout with a spinner in it that uses the drawables. In fact, I will edit my answer to include such and you can copy paste and edit in your response. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty simple. I recommend you to take a look at official docs about Styles and Themes anyway (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Comment: So I create an eclipse program with a Toasting spinner -- nothing more -- but when I try to run the project, eclipse red-lines `@styles/SpinnerAppTheme`; even after I change to `@appthem_styles/SpinnerAppTheme` it still red-lines it and complains: no resource found that matches the given name; I also cleaned, still error.

Comment: `@styles/` is a reserved uri in android, and can't reflect the actual name of styles.xml Just use `@styles/SpinnerAppTheme`

Comment: Have you merged the unzipped res/ folder into your project res/?

Comment: Yes and it complained: `style="@styles/SpinnerAppTheme"`. Yes I merged the whole thing. Do I have to edit the manifest? I followed the example to the letter.

Comment: Oh sorry: just realized a typo. It's @style/ not @styles/